# Binding JQuery to infopath form

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, binding, infopath

I'm trying to set up a form for a sharepoint list using infopath. However, I require some extra functionality so I'm trying to do something with jquery but I can never bind anything in the form.

I added a new content editor web part with this content

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function readyCall() {
    $('select').each(function() {
        $(this).change(function() {
            alert('n');
        });
    });
}
$(window).load(function() {
    window.setTimeout(readyCall, 1500);
});</script>​​​
```

Comment: `$("select").change(function(){...})` should be enough to bind the event you dont have to loop over the `select`...

Comment: Ah yes you are correct. I hadn't done jquery in a while so I forgot that it automatically returned every element instead of just the first. I still need a way to get it to actually bind though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $('select').change(function() {
            alert('n');
      });
});
</script>​​​
```